# Why do I get a blank page after any saving in joomla 3 administration?

Tags: joomla, administration

I have turned debugging on, and max error display, but even when saving these settings I get a blank page, nothing. Saving a module, the same. saving an article, the same. I reload the page and the changes were made/saved, but it gets extremely annoying to reload things twice

Comment: also I have Jevents and when I try to add a new event, blank again and it when I reload it takes me to the index administration, not a new event, tried disabling the component and still the same, any ideas?

Comment: Probably best to check with jEvents, but otherwise you might want to try at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Blank screen would indicate fatal error
-you need to enable error reporting in joomla configuration (e.g. set it to maximum).
And look for exact error related to plugins or configurations and resolve it as per error existence.